# Running a K-means (.fit) gives error:Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps but got %s." % type(params)

Tags: python, pyspark, k-means

I am running a k-means algorithm. My feature are DoubleType and have no nulls, but I get :
raise TypeError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps but got %s." % type(params). Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

```
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py:205, in Estimator.fit(self, dataset, params)
    203         return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    204     else:
--> 205         return self._fit(dataset)
    206 else:
    207     raise TypeError(
    208         "Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "
    209         "but got %s." % type(params)
    210     )

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py:381, in JavaEstimator._fit(self, dataset)
    380 def _fit(self, dataset: DataFrame) -> JM:
--> 381     java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    382     model = self._create_model(java_model)
    383     return self._copyValues(model)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py:378, in JavaEstimator._fit_java(self, dataset)
    375 assert self._java_obj is not None
    377 self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 378 return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)    1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\    1317     self.command_header +\    1318  args_command +\    1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART    1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(    1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:    1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:162, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    160 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    161     try:
--> 162         return f(*a, **kw)
    163     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    164         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o13759.fit. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 4052.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
9.3 in stage 4052.0 (TID 29072) (10.1.2.11 executor 0): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion 
failed  at...
```